# vimdiff: disable option iwhiteeol in diffopt

Tags: vimdiff

I want to see trailing white space differences using internal diff. By default vim uses iwhilteeol. Is there a way to turn this option off?

Answer (score 2):

My vim doesn't use `iwhiteeol` by default:

```
                        *'dip'* *'diffopt'*
'diffopt' 'dip'     string  (default "internal,filler")
            global
            {not available when compiled without the |+diff|
            feature}
    Option settings for diff mode.  It can consist of the following items.
    All are optional.  Items must be separated by a comma.
```

But to disable it:

```
set diffopt-=iwhiteeol
```

You can also

```
set list listchars^=trail:.
```

to show trailing whitespace

Comment: I know how to disable an option. My diffopt is blank, but diff still ignores trailing white space.

Comment: @user1602 that should fix your issue. Diff or vimdiff, just to be clear? You might see our post on [debugging your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003)